# How do I ouput a node reference field using a node reference template in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

In drupal 6 you can create templates to control how node reference fields are output on a content type basis using the suggestion below:

```
node-nodereference-exampletype.tpl.php
```

and then output a node reference field that references 'exampletype' nodes in a node template like so:

```
$node->examplenodereference[0]['view'];
```

The file naming conventions and output syntax have changed in drupal 7.

Working off the information at this link http://drupal.org/node/998848 I have tried template suggestions like these with no luck:

```
node--nodereference--exampletype.tpl.php
node-nodereference--exampletype.tpl.php
node--nodereference-exampletype.tpl.php
node-node-reference-exampletype.tpt.php
and so on...
```

I have tried adjusting the display mode for the field from teaser to full content etc.

I have tried outputting the field with:

```
print render($content['field_example']);
```

and

```
print $field_screening_movie_title;
```

and variations on the above.

What is the correct way to name a node reference template file in drupal 7? Do I need to use the render function to output a node reference field using the template?

Thanks

Comment: how do you create node reference? with entity reference module? or something else?

Comment: The node references have been created with the 'References' module http://drupal.org/project/references

Answer (score 1):

This module has one `display formatter` named `Rendered node`, in its setting you can select `view mode` which `referenced node` will render in that `view mode`.

so you can define new `view mode` and configure `referenced node` in that `view mode`

have a look at this post: http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes